# gsutil no se ejecuta en script bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Estoy creando un script en bash para poder mover una data y resulta que al ejecutar el comando

```
/usr/bin/gsutil -m cp -r archivo destino
```

El mismo no se ejecuta al momento de activarlo de manera automatizada, lo ejecuto manual y el mismo funciona correctamente tanto fuera como dentro de mi script. He cambiado de permisos y he intentado varias veces como root (y www-data) ya que el script es ejecutado por usuario nologin llamada www-data pero no tengo resultado positivo.

El comando lo automatizo desde un sistema fusionpbx a través de la aplicación system que permite ejecutar un comando(script) durante una llamada.

El sistema base es Debian11

Comment: Es dificil tratar de dar una respuesta si no se tienen los logs del error. Tendrías los logs del comando a la mano? No hay algún archivo de registro donde se vea como el programa esta corriendo el comando, cuales son sus variables de entorno y qué logs arroja?

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil` necesita credenciales (sp?) para conectarse a GCS.

Lo mas probable es que `gsutil` no puede encontrar esas credenciales cuando esta corriendo en "manera automatizada" (cron?).  La documentación (hasta donde yo se, solo en Inglés) explica como usar un archivo con las credenciales :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#gsutilauth

Normalmente `gsutil` usa las credenciales en `$HOME/.config/gcloud` (en Windows es `%APPDATA%/gcloud`).

Comment: Estaba ejecutandolo desde un script bash y la aplicación propia del sistema fusionpbx ejecutaba el script. Decidí sacar la parte de gsutil y colocarla en crontab y funciona correctamente, pero pierdo control de registro ya que esta en duro en el crontab. Se tendría que crear un script nuevo desde crontab incluyendo el comando gsutil.